# Laravel filter by URL with form

Tags: laravel, forms, url, search, filter

I am little bit new in Laravel, I use Laravel 6. I need to implement filter, I have POST form of 7 parameters. After submit I would like to filter data based on filter and generate corresponding URL, e.g.../public/en/orders/param1/param2/param3.../param7

I'd like to do it by URL because you can send link and 2nd side will see the same.
My biggest issue is that I can't find way how to transform data from form to URL.

I don't even know if POST is neccessary, I think GET is enough.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Why do you use query string instead of url params?

Comment: I have no problem with .../public/en/orders/?param1={value1}&param2={value2} but neither this I know how to create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use query string, in your routes file you can create a new route like this

```
Route::get('/orders/', 'yourController@action');
```

and in your controller get all query string with $request variable :

```
public function action (Request $request){
     $param1 = $request->get('param1');
     .....
}
```

You can see and test all params by dd function in your controller:

```
dd($request->all());
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have a question, maybe its stupid but I am completely lost there. I'll submit the form, I'll use Route like you wrote. I'll make stuff in controller, then return back and will I have URL like ../public/en/orders/?param1={value1}&param2={value2}?

Comment: If at the end of the controller you return to the page from which you sent the form, yes the url has all query strings.

Comment: Ok,thanks, it seems to be working but I had to use GET in form. Now I need to get rid of parameter token and submit.

Comment: csrt token... I think it can be removed from GET form